# Pointer to Array of 10 NodeLists? OR Array that contains Pointers to 10 NodeLists Objects

Tags: arrays, pointers, c++11

```
struct NodeList * headNodePtrList;

headNodePtrList= new NodeList[10];
```

Is the above Pointer to Array of 10 NodeLists objects? OR

Array that contains 10 Pointers to 10 NodeLists Objects

```
headNodePtrList[list].headOfList=newNode;
```

When I try to do the above it works, however if I do

```
headNodePtrList[list] -> headOfList=newNode;
```

base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘NodeList’. I understand what it is saying but I always thought that the top 2 lines created an array of 10 NodeList Pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct NodeList * headNodePtrList;
headNodePtrList = new NodeList[10];
```

> Is the above Pointer to Array of 10 NodeLists objects? OR Array that contains 10 Pointers to 10 NodeLists Objects

It is none of them. `headNodePtrList` is *a pointer* to a location where you have reserved `10 * sizeof(NodeList)` bytes of memory.

When you are accessing a single element from this array, your compiler actually takes the base address of your pointer `headNodePtrList` and adds `x` times `sizeof(NodeList)` no its address. Here is what I mean:

```
headNodePtrList[4].int_member = 1234;
```

is the same as:

```
*(headNodePtrList + 4 * sizeof(NodeList)).int_member = 1234;
```

---

**Explaination:**

A simple array `my_array[3]` of `struct my_struct`

```
struct my_struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

will be arranged like this in (example) memory:

```
| Memory Address | Reserved for                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    0x0000           my_array[0].a and where my_array is pointing at
    0x0004           my_array[0].b
    0x0008           my_array[1].a
    0x000C           my_array[1].b
    0x0010           my_array[2].a
    0x0014           my_array[2].b
```

as you access e.g. `my_array[1].b` the compiler will basically create an address that reads from the address `my_array + 1 * sizeof(my_struct) + offsetof(my_struct, b)` where the [`offsetof()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) macro delivers offset of the struct member `b` inside the struct `my_struct`.

---

The error

```
base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘NodeList’
```

Means that what's left of `->` is not a pointer. In fact you dereference your pointer `headNodePtrList` with the brackets `[]`.

```
headNodePtrList[list] -> headOfList = newNode;
```

should simply be

```
headNodePtrList[index].headOfList = newNode;
```

Btw: Don't chose the name `list` for an index variable! Name them `index` or `indexList` or ..

Comment: struct NodeList * headNodePtrList=new NodeList[10];   So this is essentially a SINGLE Pointer to a location that has the size of 10 Nodelist objects/structs. 

 struct NodeList * TenNodeListPointers[10]={nullptr}; // this however is an array of 10 pointers...Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Well yes, it points to a location where you have guaranteed valid memory at least for `10 * sizeof(NodeList)` bytes you can access without worries (assuming `new` returned a non-null pointer of course). Yes, `TenNodeListPointers` is a pointer to a location where you have reserved bytes for 10 pointers to a `NodeList` aka `NodeList*`.

Comment: And of course one would refer to `headNodePtrList` and `TenNodeListPointers` as *arrays* but I wanted you to become aware of what those two *really* are: Just pointers to a location. What they are pointing at and if that memory is valid is something you have to take care of.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. The explanation helped a lot. I have been out of touch with C++ and trying to get back into it. Its a lot of fun and pleasure that there are guys like you who are willing to explain concepts in a lucid manner. The compiler 4.8.2 gcc is a cool tool. It has some good messages that are helpful.

Comment: @zeloran You're welcome :) Btw: If you want to accept answers you can click below the up and downvote buttons so other users can see that your question hes been answered.